# setting up SourceTree for multiple related Lotus Notes databases under single Project ODP

Tags: database, xpages, multiple-instances, sourcetree, odp

I have multiple Notes Templates, all related to a single application/project.

QUESTION: Instead of creating a single ODP project folder for each of the multiple databases that make up a single application, I'd like to create a single ODP Project folder in order to hold the multiple-related Notes Templates. Do I still need to create dedicated project ODB folders underneath the primary application/project ODB directory -OR- can I simply create the single ODP project folder representing the overall application and then add each individual template database into the same single application/project ODB directory?

The reason I ask is that when a new feature is added to the overall application, it's quite possible that the new feature may 'touch/span' across multiple databases within the application.

I'd like to produce a single Release # for each feature, whether or not the new feature only involves a single database in the application -OR- if the feature spans multiple databases within the application.

I think setting up individual ODP directories for each database would eventually become a nightmare when trying to correlate/identify all the databases involved for a given feature/release # as each database is likely to have differing Release numbers as time goes on, especially if they were created and tracked individually, Whereas, if a given Release # could track single to multiple databases application changes for a given release number, it would be easier and more logical (I would think).

Comment: Just as David Leedy said, a git repository (or hg, etc.) doesn't care how many of what are inside of it, it just tracks its component files. Your multiple apps can have each of their respective ODPs in side of a single repo and you can track the collected bunch without issue. So, the project folder is really the repo folder that holds your one-to-many ODPs.

Answer (score 3):

You want to have a project folder and then a sub folder for each On disk Project.
/MyApp
    /db1-ODP
    /db2-ODP
    /dbx-ODP

You put the /MyApp under source control so everything is in the project.

A new feature could involved a single .nsf or multiple .nsf's then.

It should not be a nightmare.  The whole point of SourceTree/SourceControl is to keep everything in sync.  So once things are setup, you really shouldn't care about the ODP folders again.  It's SourceTree's job to care about that.  Then if you ever need to revert a feature or do a hot fix, SourceTree keeps all the db's in sync.

I've talked about this a couple times on my NotesIn9 ScreenCast.  I forget the show #'s at the moment but there should be some examples there if you need them.

This is the best practice way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the slides for [SHOW 103](http://www.intec.co.uk/show-103-source-control-an-end-to-end-solution/) which I did at IBM Connect in 2014 (**warning** because it's a Show and Tell, it's a large slide deck). I show how to create a project with the repo in sub-folders. This is one of the huge benefits of using an external source control solution rather than relying on embedding GIT in DDE. I recorded the Domino Designer part of it (separate from the Stash / Redmine installation) in [NotesIn9 140](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TivgBeOHcEo).